# Как сделать автоматическое приветствие нового пользователя в группе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

сразу к делу:

**Python:** 3.8

**Библиотека:** [Python Telegram Bot](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

*Основной код бота:*

```
def do_start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """ Функция обработчик команды /start """
    pass
   

def do_echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """ Функция обработчик сообщений """
    pass
 

def do_help(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """ Функция обработчик команды /help """
    pass    


def main():
    req = Request(
        connect_timeout=0.5,
    )

    bot = Bot(
        request=req,
        token=TOKEN,
    )

    updater = Updater(
        bot=bot,
        use_context=True,
    )


    # Обработчики команд
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", do_start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, do_echo))

     updater.start_polling()
        updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

С обработкой сообщений, проблем нет, интересует момент **каким образом именно в моем можно/правильнее отлавливать события добавления в чат нового участника** и тут же его приветствовать.

Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: @Danis, нет, используются разные библиотеки.

Comment: извините, не знал

Answer (score 0):

Нужен соответствующий обработчик. Новый юзер в чате это все еще сообщение, поэтому он будет выглядеть так:

```
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.status_update.new_chat_members, do_hello))
```

Почти все подобные вещи в данной библиотеке собраны в Message, так что в будущем проверяйте соответствующее поле именно там.